# How do I connect to Connect to Db2 with JDBC and SSL and avoid the error "A DRDA Data Stream Syntax Error was detected. Reason: 0x3. ERRORCODE=-4499"?

Tags: db2, db2-luw

I'm trying to connect to Db2 but I get the following error message

```
[jcc][t4][2034][11148][4.25.23] Execution failed due to a distribution protocol error that caused deallocation of the conversation.
A DRDA Data Stream Syntax Error was detected.  Reason: 0x3. ERRORCODE=-4499, SQLSTATE=58009
```

What does that mean, and how do I get connected?

Comment: See https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/faq-jdbc-driver-data-stream-syntax-error

Comment: Unfortunately, at the time of writing, that page only suggests that error 0x3 "may be caused by a firewall",  but that is not what I find from my experience.

Comment: Do you work for IBM , can't you get it changed?

Comment: I have made that suggestion :-)

Comment: Latest: i had same issue, problem was database request was going throw wrong hostname.

Answer (score 8):

Well the short answer is that you might just need to add the  `sslConnection=true` JDBC parameter

I.e. your JDBC URL needs to look something like this

```
db2://db2whoc-abcdefg.services.eu-de.bluemix.net:50001/BLUDB:sslConnection=true;
```

Depending on what tool you are using, you might edit the URL directly, or add as an extra JDBC property

Now the above only works if you are using a reasonably recent JDBC driver.
The `DigiCertGlobalRootCA.crt` used by e.g. Db2 on Cloud, Db2 Warehouse and Db2 Warehouse on Cloud was not bundled in older drivers. You can cross-reference the driver version (e.g. `4.25.23` in the question) against the drivers listed here. [DB2 JDBC Driver Versions and Downloads](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/node/382667) and upgrade if not on the latest release

If your Db2 server is using a different certificate (for example a self-signed certificate) then you would need to download the certificate, and set the JDBC property `sslCertLocation` to point to it's location, or you can  import the certificate into a local store, and use `sslTrustStoreLocation` and `sslTrustStorePassword` and a import the cert into their local certificate store.

All these JDBC properties are described on the
[Common IBM Data Server Driver for JDBC and SQLJ properties for all supported database products](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.java.doc/src/tpc/imjcc_r0052038.html) page